# How to determine if IE11 or Edge in IE compatibility mode is used

Tags: internet-explorer-11

Anybody knows how to detect the browser type? Especially to make a difference between **Edge in IE compatibility mode** and **"real" IE11**.

HTTP headers (e.g. User-Agent) are same in both cases, so that cannot be used to determine the browser.

And so far I haven't found any js differences either.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, pages using Edge IE mode actually run `Internet Explorer` based on the MSHTML engine, instead of Edge based on Chroiumn.

In addition, you can also learn more details about IE mode from this blog: [Internet Explorer 11 desktop app retirement FAQ](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/internet-explorer-11-desktop-app-retirement-faq/ba-p/2366549)

Comment: thanks, I'm aware of the engine and other technical details. There is just a need to know if the user is still using IE11 or Edge. Since there is still an ActiveX component in use, it is not possible to switch normal Edge mode or other browser. Yet.

Comment: As I mentioned, I think it is impossible to achieve such a function if use the code.